# Reported speech without backshift

Tags: grammar, reported-speech, backshifting

Please look at this example of reported speech:

> A friend told me he made an order 5 months ago.

I think that even though this is reported speech, there's no backshift here because of ***5 months ago***. The date of the order is clearly stated.

Is my explanation correct?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I don't see a question here.

Comment: I just would like to know if I am right by explaining that there is  no backshift due to 5 months ago.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you saying that backshift is **not allowed** in that example? Or are you saying that backshift is **optional** in that example? Please update your question post to reflect whatever question it is that you are asking.

Comment: Optional of course as it is clearly stated that the order was before "today"

Comment: No, there is no ***"of course"*** in it. You need to edit your post to make it clear what you are saying and what you are asking for.

Comment: So in this case is past perfect optional ? Why or why not

Comment: So sorry because the sentence is in fact A friend told me TODAY  he made an order 5 months ago . I forgot" today "

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is better saying:

> A friend told me he had made an order 5 months ago.

If you introduce the past perfect the backshift is implicitly done.

Comment: Welcome to the ELL :-). To avoid answers that look like they are opinion-based (this are usually reserved for comments) it is preferable to include some references and/or reasoning that is a bit more detailed.